# How to read Greste?

Tags: pronunciation

> One of the brothers of the jailed Australian journalist Peter **Greste** says the announcement by Egypt's president that he won't interfere in the case is "damaging, heartbreaking news". 
>   ([part](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/466) of Aussie ABC; original source [here](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4032450.htm))

I hear *Greste* as /'grestə/. Am I right? If right, are e’s in the end of words, generally, read as schwa /ə/, in English, or is it a special case because the name has come from no English origin etc.?

Comment: I don't think there's a rule in English that tells you whether or how to pronounce the final <e>, unfortunately.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the pronunciation of (foreign) proper nouns.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I guess the OP is about For English Users how to read the words that end with e. Is it off-topic? For Korean users, it is read /greste/. How about English users?? I don't think it's off topic at all.

Comment: @Listenever: Asking about specific proper nouns that don't really have any significant "anglicised" component doesn't seem particularly relevant to the general case for actual English words. Where I would guess the final "e" is more likely to "silently" modify the preceding vowel than to actually be enunciated itself. But this question doesn't get remotely close to even exploring *that* potentially useful issue. Whatever - everyone is entitled to their own opinion; I've just stated mine.

Comment: I want to add - this is almost certainly too localised to be useful in future. The pronunciation of names can even come down to personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter Greste is of Latvian descent, his real name is **Pēteris Greste**, indeed pronounced [**ˈgrɛstǝ**] in English.